# How to correctly use datetime data on the continuous axis of a Google Chart?

Tags: javascript, datetime, charts, google-visualization

So as seen in the code snippet below, I'm just trying to create a chart/control combination dashboard via [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls) and I'm having some difficulties with datetime fields, despite following the [reference material](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes) on that.

My areas of confusion are as follows: 
1. Why do the dates shown on the chart appear to be off by one month? I've entered dates for August & September, yet September & October are showing up on the chart.
2. Why does the chart displayed for the ChartRangeFilter appear to jump back to older dates (around the October 2 mark)?

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
    packages: ['corechart', 'controls']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

function drawDashboard() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        [{
            "type": "datetime",
            "label": "date"
        }, {
            "type": "number",
            "label": "presence"
        }],
        ["Date(2017, 08, 29, 12, 17, 25)", 1],
        ["Date(2017, 08, 29, 15, 06, 39)", 0],
        ["Date(2017, 08, 29, 17, 28, 27)", 1],
        ["Date(2017, 08, 30, 09, 14, 33)", 0],
        ["Date(2017, 08, 30, 13, 17, 28)", 1],
        ["Date(2017, 08, 30, 14, 03, 52)", 0],
        ["Date(2017, 08, 30, 17, 31, 12)", 1],
        ["Date(2017, 08, 30, 22, 14, 45)", 0],
        ["Date(2017, 08, 30, 22, 15, 48)", 1],
        ["Date(2017, 08, 31, 08, 41, 30)", 0],
        ["Date(2017, 08, 31, 13, 22, 06)", 1],
        ["Date(2017, 08, 31, 13, 33, 33)", 0],
        ["Date(2017, 08, 31, 15, 23, 41)", 1],
        ["Date(2017, 08, 31, 15, 48, 11)", 0],
        ["Date(2017, 08, 31, 22, 15, 45)", 1],
        ["Date(2017, 09, 01, 09, 18, 40)", 0],
        ["Date(2017, 09, 01, 19, 29, 50)", 1],
        ["Date(2017, 09, 02, 11, 24, 07)", 0],
        ["Date(2017, 09, 02, 14, 13, 04)", 1],
        ["Date(2017, 09, 03, 09, 48, 48)", 0],
        ["Date(2017, 09, 03, 13, 27, 42)", 1],
        ["Date(2017, 09, 03, 13, 51, 46)", 0],
        ["Date(2017, 09, 03, 15, 44, 59)", 1],
        ["Date(2017, 09, 04, 10, 02, 20)", 0]
    ]);

    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));

    var chart_options = {
        "legend": { "position": "none" },
        "vAxis": {
            "ticks": [{
                "f": "Not Present",
                "v": 0
            }, {
                "f": "Present",
                "v": 1
            }],
            "maxValue": 1,
            "minValue": 0
        },
        "title": "Chart"
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'SteppedAreaChart',
        'containerId': 'chart',
        'options': chart_options
    });

    var control_options = {
        "filterColumnLabel": "date"
    };

    var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
        'containerId': 'control',
        'options': control_options,
    });

    dashboard.bind(control, chart);
    dashboard.draw(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard">
    <div id="chart" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
    <div id="control" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: JavaScript, and most languages, use month indices that start with 0.  Also, avoid prefixing your numbers with 0 because they look like octal values.

Comment: Ah yes, that fixes both issues.  Thank you.  Certainly this is correct for JavaScript.  I think "most" languages is a bit of a sweeping generalisation though.  Python [for example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects), which was used to generate this data, uses the more human intuitive 1-12.

Comment: @dlaliberte: I don't appear to be able to mark your comment as the answer. Happy to do so if you enter it as an answer rather than comment?

Comment: Thanks. I seem to answer the 'months off by one' issue about once a month. There are several potential duplicate questions in stack overflow.  So just uptick the question and I will be happy.